# How to show scrollbar on mobile Safari in mat-select?

Tags: html, css, angular, safari, angular-material

I have an angular material mat-select with many options inside. With the default styles, it is not obvious that there are more options than those that are shown so I would like the scrollbar to be visible.

I have tried these styles but they don't work in mobile safari. I'm not sure if it's an angular material problem or safari specific problem.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important; 
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.8) !important; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot of opened mat-select]

Comment: Have you use overflow:scroll element in your css file?

Comment: @Suraj-Ui: I have tried but it does not work. Which not surprising as the scroll should apply to the overlay component, not to the mat-select itself.

Comment: @Suraj-Ui did you solve this issue. still i am facing it